# How to set the sentiment attribute on a Span?

Tags: spacy

I'm trying thhe Keras example from spacy [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/examples#keras), but instead of suming the sentiment score in the `Doc` like that

```
for sent, label in zip(sentences, ys):
  sent.doc.sentiment += label - 0.5
```

I would like to keep the score on the sentence level like that

```
for sent, label in zip(sentences, ys):
  sent.sentiment = float(label)
```

This code give me that error

```
AttributeError: attribute 'sentiment' of 'spacy.tokens.span.Span' objects is not writable
```

Is there a setter to call instead? I tried `set_sentiment` without success.
Am I missing something? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the implementation of `Span.sentiment` [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/tokens/span.pyx#L495). You can see it is indeed not writable, because it either looks up the value in `self.doc.user_span_hooks`, or takes the average of `token.sentiment` for the tokens in that span.

[EDITED BELOW]

The sentiment of a `Token` is not context-dependent though. It uses the information present in the underlying [`Lexeme`](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#vocab). That means that any word, such as "love", would have the same sentiment value in any sentence/context.

So there's two things you can do: either write to the sentiment of the lexemes like so:

```
vocab["love"].sentiment = 3.0
```

Or implement a custom hook that allows you to define any function you want. You can do this on the span (`doc.user_span_hooks`) or token (`doc.user_token_hooks`) level:

```
doc.user_span_hooks["sentiment"] = lambda span: 10.0
```

Comment: I get the same problem with `Token`: `AttributeError: attribute 'sentiment' of 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' objects is not writable`

Comment: You're right, my original answer was not entirely correct. I updated it !

Comment: `user_span_hooks` works. What would be the advantage to use `user_span_hooks` instead of an `extension attribute`?

Comment: I think in this case the difference is small, but if you use the user hooks with the key "sentiment" you have the added advantage of `span.sentiment` and `token.sentiment` working on top of that.